# Can not take correct identifier of WebElement (Sign in at iCloud.com)

Tags: java, selenium, automation, icloud

I have trouble identifying 'sign in with Apple ID' element (at iclod.com page).

This is what I'm using now:

```
WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"account_name_text_field\"]");
username.sendKeys("my_email@icloud.com");
```

Also, I tried to use CSS created by Chropath and Ranorex, still not working.
What I'm doing wrong?

[Path to needed Element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjdzj.png)

Comment: Have you tried By.cssSelector("#account_name_text_field") ?

Answer (score 0):

The element is inside the `iframe`, you need switch first.

You can use `.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt`:

```
driver.get("https://www.icloud.com/");
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("auth-frame")));
WebElement username = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("account_name_text_field")));
username.sendKeys("my_email@icloud.com");
```

Add `WebDriverWait`, the web loading is rather long.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below solution. Iframe is associated with your web page and you need to switch to iframe before you interact with web element input box.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r" path of chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.icloud.com")
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "auth-frame")))
driver.switch_to.frame("auth-frame")
inputBox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "account_name_text_field")))
inputBox.send_keys("your test")

# switch back to main window
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**output:**

[image]

Comment: would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer from your end.

Answer (score 0):

Iframes can be tricky. You have to change focus to the frame before accessing that text box. 
Use switchTo().frame ();

It can take the following parameters :

1. switchTo().frame(int  frame number): Defining the frame index number,
   the Driver will switch to that specific frame
2. switchTo().frame(string 
       frameNameOrId): Defining the frame element or Id, the Driver will
       switch to that specific frame
3. switchTo().frame(WebElement 
       frameElement): Defining the frame web element, the Driver will
       switch to that specific frame

[image]

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
waitdriver = new WebDriverWait(driver , 10);
driver.get("https://www.icloud.com/");
driver.switchTo().frame("auth-frame"); 
waitdriver.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated( By.xpath("//*[@id=\"account_name_text_field\"]")));
WebElement textbox=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"account_name_text_field\"]"));
textbox.click();
textbox.sendKeys("HelloWorld@gmail.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The xpath pattern which you have written is wrong.
2) You can always verify the xpath or cssSelector in ChroPath before using it in your script.
3) If the element is inside iframe then you must have got the iframe xpath as well as the element xpath in ChroPath. Please use them. 
Please follow this video tutorial to make the best use of this [iframe feature](https://youtu.be/CxzrPW9yLRE) of ChroPath.